# object() takes no parameters when trying to delete model instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Every time I try to delete an instance of a specific model, I get the error:

`object() takes no parameters`

I looked for this error message, but all posts refer to a wrong **init** setup, which I don't have.

It's driving me nuts! Any idea what is causing this? Here is the model:

```
class CharacterSheet(models.Model):
    objects = ModelManager()

    save_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    character_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    root = models.TextField(
        default="{'lastId':'0', 'lastPlayerAddedId':'0', 'is_root':'true', 'type': 'section', 'direction': 'vertical'}")

    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    color = models.IntegerField(default=random_color)

    template = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="copies", on_delete=models.Empty, null=True)

    saved_on_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    @property
    def root_json(self):
        return json.loads(self.root)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Save method override"""
        super(CharacterSheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        for character in self.characters.all():
            character.save()
```

Full error stack:

```
File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_view
  1713.             return self._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _delete_view
  1737.             [obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in get_deleted_objects
  131.     collector.collect(objs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in collect
  195.             return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)

File "/home/vvdrrltv/virtualenv/rolegate.com_rolegate__django/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in collect
  222.                         field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/playerdata/charactersheet/1240/delete/
Exception Value: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the exception?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Thanks, so `field.remote_field.on_delete` is set to `object` or a subclass with no `__init__` method, that's something we can help debug.

Comment: And you have `on_delete=models.Empty` set, so that's probably the culprit!

Comment: That was it!! Thanks! Can you write a proper answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
template = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', related_name="copies", 
    on_delete=models.Empty, null=True)
```

The `on_delete` value is invalid; you need to pick [one of the valid options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

For example, if you meant the reference to be replaced by `models.Empty`, you'd have to use `models.SET(models.Empty)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Django doc for ForeignKey.on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). Possible values are:

- models.CASCADE
- models.PROTECT
- models.SET_NULL
- models.SET_DEFAULT
- models.SET()
- models.DO_NOTHING

The value you used (`models.Empty`) in field `template` is invalid and is probably the cause of your error